# Is it possible to recreate an early bound CRM entity from a RemoteExecutionContext?

Tags: c#, servicebus, dynamics-crm-online, azure-servicebus-queues

Is it possible to recreate an early bound `CRM` entity from a `RemoteExecutionContext`?

I've got messages in a `Service Bus` queue that are `RemoteExecutionContext` coming from `CRM Online`. I can happily get the late bound properties from the message if I cast as an `Entity`, but I'd rather work with an early bound object

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, once you have casted the object as type Entity. You can call the Entity.ToEntity <T>() method. In effect this is casting to the early bound Entity type.

Comment: @Alessi 's answer is spot on. Add it as answer and i'll happily upvote it